# how can i show flow is incompressible?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

How can I understand the flow is incompressible or not with this information at 4 edges?[image]

Comment: Hint: If the fluid is incompressible, whatever goes in must come out. Can you express that using derivatives?

Comment: If the divergence of the velocity is zero at a given point, then it is incompressible at that point. So you can prove the region is compressible if you show any of those 4 corners are not incompressible. However, since you can't assume knowledge of the flow field within the entire region, I don't think you should be able to prove it is incompressible everywhere even if all 4 corners are compressible.

Comment: thanks Christian and choward
@ choward i think as you say cant prove any place of this rigion isn't incompressible even 4 corners are incompressible.

Answer (score 4):

Continuity equation is given by

$ \frac{D \rho}{ D t}+\rho \nabla \cdot \vec{U}=0$,

if it is incompressible then

$\nabla \cdot \vec{U}=0$

Just check if the velocity is solenoidal.If it is, then it is incompressible.